# Django model search concatenated string

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I am trying to use a Django model to for a record but then return a concatenated field of two different tables joined by a foreign key.

I can do it in SQL like this:

```
SELECT 
    location.location_geoname_id as id,
    CONCAT_WS(', ', location.location_name, region.region_name, country.country_name) AS 'text'
FROM
    geonames_location as location
JOIN
    geonames_region as region
ON
    location.region_geoname_id = region.region_geoname_id
JOIN
    geonames_country as country
ON
    region.country_geoname_id = country.country_geoname_id
WHERE
    location.location_name like 'location'
ORDER BY
    location.location_name, region.region_name, country.country_name
LIMIT 10;
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this using Django models? Or do I need to just use SQL for this one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the SQL to return the concatenated field? Why not query the models in the usual way (with `select_related()`) and then concatenate in Python? Or if you're worried about querying more columns than you need, use `values_list`:

```
locations = Location.objects.values_list(
    'location_name', 'region__region_name', 'country__country_name')
location_texts = [','.join(l) for l in locations]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write raw query for this in your code like that and later on you can concatenate.

Example:

```
org = Organization.objects.raw('SELECT organization_id, name FROM organization where is_active=1 ORDER BY name')
```

Keep one thing in a raw query you have to always fetch primary key of table, it's mandatory. Here organization_id is a primary key of contact_organization table.

And it's depend on you which one is useful and simple(raw query or model query).